# Is there a way I can assert that a list with properties has certain values

Tags: java, assert, matcher

I have an `List<MyClass>`. 
`MyClass` has a property called `rollNo`

and I want to assert that my `List` contains `MyClass` objects and those objects include object with rollNo: 31 object with rollNo: 32 and object with rollNo: 33

This is what I have tried and so far not have been able to make it work:

```
assertThat(myClassObjects, contains (
            hasProperty("rollNo", is(21L)),
            hasProperty("rollNo", is(22L))
    ));
```

Comment: Could you add a code example that you're working with, what you've tried, and what isn't working for you?

Comment: @cantido I have updated the question with the code